# docker-compose inside Alpine container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I'm attempting to bundle my app (code, Dockerfiles and a docker-compose script) together inside a single image for easy deployment (entrypoint will just `docker-compose up`). My Dockerfile for this top level app image looks like so

```
FROM alpine:latest
COPY . /app
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache docker py-pip openrc && pip install docker-compose
```

When I run this image, it seems that dockerd hasn't started, being absent from `top` results; `docker ps` reports "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
". If however I do `service docker start`, this returns " * WARNING: docker is already starting". Is there anything special I need to do to get Docker working side of an Alpine container?

Comment: Did you install docker properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker consists of docker daemon, who runs all services, and CLI, used to interact with daemon (ok, there are lots of other parts, but these are most important). Installing `docker-compose` does not install daemon, regardless of what message you are getting from `service` command.

To use `docker` inside container, you have to use `docker-in-docker` image. It is called `docker:dind`. Inherit from it (instead of `alpine`) and enjoy.

But before read [this article](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind), which explains why it is not a great idea and what are other ways to use docker inside container (tip: you can call host's docker daemon from inside container with just mounting `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` socket).

Comment: Look like it's doing the right thing but the inner containers are lacking external networking? Is there a way to pipe this down in a similar manner?

Comment: Don't get you. Inner container's do not lack networking, they don't have daemon unless it is explicitly installed. Using `/var/run/docker.sock` eliminates this issue by granting them connectivity to **host's** container. But this is Unix socket, which is not pure networking.

Comment: Yep, it appears the problem is actually the logging for one of the internal containers/applications stopping (or being swallowed/hidden/etc.) despite the container/application continuing to run fine

Answer (score 4):

If you can't or don't want to inherit from `docker:dind` as mentioned in [grapes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10524386/grapes) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54711789/7873775) there is an option to use `alpine` as a base image and install Docker CLI and Docker Compose.

To keep image small some dependencies can be deleted after Docker Compose installation:

```
FROM alpine:3.11

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache docker-cli python3 && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .docker-compose-deps python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make && \
    pip3 install docker-compose && \
    apk del .docker-compose-deps
```

This image doesn't contain Docker Engine and Docker-in-Dcoker approach has to be used by mounting `/var/run/docker.sock` from the host

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock <image name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this to get docker-compose

```
apk update && apk add --no-cache --virtual docker-cli python3 .docker-compose-deps python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make python3 py3-pip py-pip curl libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev rust cargo make

pip install docker-compose
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker is a client-server application. It has docker client (`docker` binary) and docker daemon (`dockerd`)

You get this error because you installed only docker client, not docker daemon inside Dockerfile.

To resolve this you have several options:

- use [docker:dind](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) image which has both docker daemon and client inside
- map docker daemon socket from the docker host to the container with docker client
- let docker client connect remotely to docker daemon (which may run anywhere, e.g. inside container, vm, bare-metal, etc...)

I wrote how to [create docker in docker agent image](https://www.rokpoto.com/jenkins-docker-in-docker-agent/) and you can see the example there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply download last version of docker-compose release form [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) then move it in /usr/bin and add it access to run, like below:

```
RUN apk add docker
RUN wget https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.24.5/docker-compose-linux-x86_64
RUN mv docker-compose-linux-x86_64 /usr/bin/docker-compose
RUN chmod +x  /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

You need to run your container with below command:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock {your-alpine-image}
```