# Run docker-compose inside docker:dind

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This question is not the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711502/docker-compose-inside-alpine-container). The issue in that question is with starting a `docker` instance but this one is associated with binding `docker` with `docker-compose`.

I am trying to run `docker-compose` inside `docker:dind` image.
So created my own image with following `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM docker:dind
RUN apk add py-pip
RUN apk add python-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make
RUN pip install docker-compose
RUN addgroup ${USER} docker
```

But running `docker-compose` command throws following error,

```
yarn run v1.16.0
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run test
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

lerna ERR! yarn run test stderr:
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

How can it be fixed. The os in `docker:dind` is `Alpine` linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker-compose inside Alpine container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711502/docker-compose-inside-alpine-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build docker-compose image from scratch.

There is [official](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose/) docker-compose image available on dockerhub. Use that.

For instructions on how to run it, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56785780/6790948) out.

Comment: @asur let me know if it helped.

Comment: Is the docker daemon running, while running the image you point to? Having the daemon running, by default from the entrypoint, is the whole point of `dind`.